# Scroll view frame width is wider than content size?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UIScrollView` and I am trying to set the `contentSize` correctly.

The output of `scrollView.frame.size` is `(600.0, 600.0)`. These are the same numbers I see in the storyboard. The weird thing is that if I do `scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(600, 600)` I get a scroll view with **a lot** of scrollable space. Intuitively, if the `contentSize` is equal to the size of the scroll view, there should be no scrollable space, and there certainly should not be a lot of it. What is wrong with my size?

Edit: I should add that my `zoomScale` is set to some number < 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of `scrollView.frame.size` is `(600.0, 600.0)` only in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`. This is because the Autolayout has not been set yet in these methods.

If your try to log `scrollView.frame.size` in `viewDidAppear`, then you will get the correct frame size of the scroll view according to screen size (given that `Autolayout` is implemented correctly), which would be much smaller than the `contentSize`.

That is why you get a lot of scrollable space when you set `scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(600, 600)`.

Comment: So what is the solution? I can't add this code to `viewDidAppear` because then the user can see a jump in the views.

Comment: @Max I answered your current question *What is wrong with my size?*. Your question does not explain what you want to achieve. Please elaborate on that.

Comment: I want to set the content size of the scroll view based on the current size of the scroll view frame.

Comment: you can write this in `viewDidAppear` --->> `scrollView.contentSize = scrollView.frame.size`

Comment: Using that method causes a visible jump in the scroll view content. Is there any way to do this before rendering?

Comment: are all your autolayout constraints properly set for the scroll view? if yes then setting the content size wont be required.

Comment: I'm also trying to zoom the scroll view and that zoom needs to be done before rendering.

Comment: Do it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, just beware that it will be called multiple times.